# Set to null everything that points to that Object

Tags: java, structure

I'm writing a Java program in which are Survivor objects. There is and will be many attributes (e.g this.leader), Lists (e.g allSurvivors, femaleSurvivors) and maybe other things referencing them, everywhere in the source. I want the cleanest way -and also when considering the coding in the long run-, to do the following :

**When a Survivor dies, it is removed from the Lists in which he was, and the attributes that were "pointing" to him are now set to null.**

I would like it to be in such a way that, if I add another List for a new feature, I won't have to remember to initialize it a certain way, or anything. I would just have to use it as usual, and the dead Survivors would be removed just because of the structure of the classes, or anything I will write now with your help.

The problem with Java is that, when a Survivor dies, let's say I remove it from the main list, it will still be in, maybe, femaleSurvivors, and won't be deleted because the garbage collector still detects a reference. I don't know if in c++, pointers to a deleted object are null, but that would be close to the expected behavior.

I don't care if there is a huge work to do now, complex classes and sub-classes extending List or whatever, as long as I won't have to care about it tomorrow.

I have already thought about using a meta-class, which would be the real Survivor, but there were flaws and it wouldn't work. I also thought about using my own List class, which would be updating staticly all new lists and remove the dead from these lists when necessary, but it also failed, and wouldn't work with simple attributes.
I guess I could also check for a dead boolean before doing anything with that list, but that's far away from the clean code ideal I'm trying to reach.

Thanks a lot for your help.

EDIT : Since it appears it was not very clear, as for now, the class Survivor DOES represent an actual survivor. Examples of actual attributes are name and isFemale.
But I still need lists for things you can't deduce from the survivor, such as currentScavengingTeam.

Comment: What `List` object are you using?  You could always remove an object from an `ArrayList`, so you won't have to worry about re-initializing the `ArrayList` itself.  If you want an object null, then just set is as so:  `variableName = null`.

Comment: It sounds like your design could use some improvement. Perhaps you could provide us with more info on what these lists are used for, so we could offer advice on improving your design to avoid the problem you mentioned.

Comment: I'm using LinkedList, so there is a remove method. But the problem is when other lists/variables still own the survivor, and I don't know which ones. I use lists to spread some of the survivors in not-necessarily-distinct groups, and of course, there is allSurvivors.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bad design decision, I don't know what "flaws" there were, but I urge you to rethink them. Having a `Survivor` class represent actual survivors even sounds a lot more reasonable.

As for your question:

If I was forced into this design, I would likely add an [EventBus](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained) (Bad! But seems inevitable in this case) for SurvivorEvents. Survivor events would represent things happening with survivors, including their death. When a survivor dies, he sends an event through this bus to all listeners with this info. Your list would be then:

```
class SurvivorList extends List<Survivor> implements SurvivorListener {
    @Override
    public void survivorUpdated(SurvivorEvent e) {
        if (e instanceOf SurvivorDiedEvent) {
            remove(e.getSurvivor());
        }
    }

    <Overridden constructor that calls super() and adds listener>
}
```

You would also be able to send various other events that change attributes on your survivors and have your collections automatically add or remove Survivors from themselves.

**Warning**: While this is a very powerful tool to use, it is VERY easy to create a huge mess of events, especially if you start sending events in response to events.

Answer (score 0):

What you want isn't possible. I suggest that you use something like `survivor.isAlive()` to determine whethere it's alive or not, you can also then remove the dead survivor references from lists as you encounter them.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a `SurvivorList` class.

```
public void add(Survivor survivor) {
    super.add(survivor);
    survivor.addHolder(this);
}

public void destroyList() {
    for (Survivor survivor : this) {
        survivor.removeHodler(this);
    }
}
```

Then, your Survivor class has methods like:

```
public void addHolder(List list) {
    holders.add(list);
}

public void removeHolder(List list) {
    holder.remove(list);
}

public void destroy() {
    for(List holder : holders) {
        holder.remove(this);
    }
}
```

Then, normal code:

```
SurvivorList sl = new SurvivorList();
Survivor s = new Survivor();
sl.add(s);

...

s.destroy();
```

Something along those lines can work. The trick is ensuring the s.destroy and sl.destroyList are called appropriately.

Comment: Typo in survivor.removeHolder(this)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are keeping track of characteristics of the survivors using the lists, when each survivor should be an object of a Survivor class, which contains all these characteristics.

For example, a Survivor object might have the following attributes and values:
(note: this is not code, just an example of the contents of a Survivor object)

```
survivorOne {
    name = "Fred"
    gender = "female"
    role = "leader"
    etc...
}
```

Then, you just have one list which has all the survivors in it, and when one dies, you just have one list to remove him/her from. And if you need to do an action on just the female survivors, for example, you just do a check that their gender is female, and if it isn't, skip that survivor and go to the next in the list.

Comment: A Survivor IS a set of characteristics (I have edited). And I can't set a role, not everyone has a role. However,I need a leader reference to do things such as leader.getName(). I won't check them all the time, especially if : there are numerous, the leader doesn't change much, and how would that work with groups (ex edit : currentScavengingTeam) ?